# Create A Help Button On The Top Right Of A Windows Form

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to know how to create this "?" button in Visual Studio. I am not sure where to find it nor what it's called.

Image:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a `HelpButton`, it will be visible once you set :

- the [`Form.HelpButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx) to `true`
- [`MaximizeBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox.aspx) to `false` and
- [`MinimizeBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimizebox.aspx) to `false`.

When this button is clicked, it raises the [`Form.HelpButtonClicked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked.aspx) Event.

**Edit:** For WPF see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009983/162671)