# What is the equal of HelpButton In Wpf Application Window?

Tags: wpf, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help “?” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009983/help-button)

In Win Form Application form Exists HelpButton in Top Of Windows
But I dont Find Equal Of It in wpf form Application Window.